# When ListView item is clicked it wont transition to next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

In my android app when an item from my `ListView` is clicked it should open up the activity `FixtureDescription` each item should open up the same activity but have it start out empty for each new item. This is my .java file and at the moment the list is populated correctly from a `AlertDialog` but when it is clicked it doesn't move from the activity it is on. Any suggestions?

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.widget.AdapterView.*;


public class RoomDescription extends ActionBarActivity {

    public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    public ArrayList<String> myFixtures = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String listItem;

    private void setFixtureName()
    {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText txtInput = new EditText(this);


        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Fixture Name");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("What is the fixture name?");
        dialogBuilder.setView(txtInput);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myFixtures.add(txtInput.getText().toString());
                populateListView();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fixture has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialogFixtureName = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialogFixtureName.show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setFixtureName();
    }

    public void onItemClick()
    {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.FixtureList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                    default:Intent i = new Intent(RoomDescription.this, FixtureDescription.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

    }
    private void populateListView()
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.items, myFixtures);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.FixtureList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_description);

        populateListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_room_description, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've introduced a method that is never used: `onItemClick()`. By using a good IDE—and I thoroughly encourage you to use Android Studio—you will see such warnings in your editor.

The OnItemClickListener should be registered in the creation of your view, in `onCreate()`.

(Similarly, the activity's `onClick()` is never executed.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnItemClickListener` is inside a method that you don't call - it is not automatically called by Android, or anything like that.

You should add the code for your `OnItemClickListener` in `onCreate()` in your `Activity` so that the click listener is initialised and then is able to perform actions on item click.

To be clear, what you have inside your `onItemClick()` method is initialising the listener so that it starts listening for a click. Since you want it to always be 'listening' for an item click, you should move the code to `onCreate()`.